# jQuery - not working with input type search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a field with input type `search`

When I try to select that with jQuery I get `VM535 jquery-git.js:1529 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: search`

Check the fiddle - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darshan_Shah/dsye8b2x/)

How do I select that field?
(note: I do not have any unique class or id applied to that field, actually it's plugin generated.)

Actually I am using `jQuery DataTable` plugin and I want to add a Go button just besides the search box. For this I am trying this workaround - to select the 
search box with jQuery and add button besides it with `insertAfter` method. Please suggest me if there is any other way for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use attribute selector in such cases. Try this:

```
alert($('input[type="search"]').val());
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/dsye8b2x/1/

Answer (score 7):

> `input:search` is not a valid [`selector(not listed in Selectors section in the docs)`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Use [*Attribute Equals Selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `input[type="search"]`

```js
alert($('input:text').val());
alert($('input[type="search"]').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="text">
<br/>
<input type="search" value="search">
<br/>
```

Comment: Yup. That was quick. Thanks.

Comment: @codeHeart, That will be an good question for `jQuery` developers.. As you could see, [`:text`](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) is there i  the docs but `:search` is missing

Comment: Ah Great! I was looking in the CSS selectors but wasn't able to find `:text` there. So its jQuery *feature*. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

you were close, do this: `alert($('input[type="search"]').val())`